# How do I make something summon when I use a fishing rod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to use the execute command but I was never able to find something where I could trigger it at the use of the fishing rod. I'm trying to make my own weapon using commands and I want to make a line of particles that do damage and deal knockback I thought a bow or fishing rod was a good place to start but I can't find any command that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a command whenever a `fishing_bobber` (end of fishing line, only spawns when you use your fishing rod) is spawned. An example:

`/execute at @e[type=minecraft:fishing_bobber] run particle minecraft:happy_villager`

If you put that command in a repeating command block it will show the happy villager particle along the path the fishing bobber takes.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed tysm.

Answer (score -1):

You have to wait until there is a bubble trail going to your bobber. After that, the bubbles will hit the bobber and it will go underwater. When that happens right click and if that doesn’t work left click.

Comment: Please read the question properly. This isn't just "how do I fish" but "how do I use commands to make something special happen when I fish"